# How to change the colour of select option's items on hover?

Tags: css, html-select

I have tried changing the select option's items background colour when the user hover over it. However, I couldn't find a way to fix the problem. I then searched it online and still was'st able to find a solution.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Really no cross-browser, cross-platform solution for what you want with just css.  Might be an option with jquery.  iOS is going to ignore your css.

Comment: would you please give me any  tips on how I could do that.

Comment: Honestly, if styling is very important, I would consider whether a select is the best option.  Something like a state or country select would definitely be a select.  Consider how little time your user will have the select box open, and ask yourself if its worth your time.  I know there are some jquery solutions but I haven't used them. Again, Im not sure how they would work on mobile, paricularly iOS.  Right now, around 70% of traffic for most sites is on mobile/tablet platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve your goal by using the bootstrap-select:

You will need the following CDN links:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.5/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

The select list with the class `selectpicker`:

```
<select id="txtTitle" class="form-control selectpicker">
    <option selected disabled value="default">Please Select</option>
    <option value="Session">Session</option>
    <option value="Class">Class</option>
</select>
```

After this you can change/add the following properties of the CSS:

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #f3969a;
}
```

and you will get this when you hover over the list items:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

// Changes each list option background to red

`.mat-list-base .mat-list-option {
  background-color: red;
}`

// Changes each list option background to blue on hover

`.mat-list-base .mat-list-option:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
yourSelectOption:hover {
    background-color: yourDesiredColor;
}
```

Notice the `:hover` after what you want to style.

Hope this helps!

Comment: this is not what I want, this changes that colour of the whole select. I just want to change colour of select's items on hover.

Comment: If you could, can you post your code, it may help us understand better